# Python function to return smallest number

Tags: python, function

I do not understand the problem, for example, the sample input is 123 the next smallest natural number is 124 but the sum here is 7 so, next 125, 126, 127, all of which do not give a sum of 6. I do not understand how you get to 132?

can someone please clarify, is it just changing one digit or more than one?

Please write a function in Python which receives a natural decimal N-digit number
(`0<N<15`) as an input and returns the minimal next N-digit number with the same sum
of digits or -1 if there isn't one.
Examples:

```
Input: Output:
123 132
0200 1001
09999999999999 18999999999999
90 -1
9999 -1
```

Comment: What problem? Can you please share the *full* problem statement?

Comment: Well `132` evidently has the same sum of digits as `123`, since it simply swapped the digits.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? What code have you written so far?

Comment: I don't need help with the code, I don't understand the problem!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The question does not say to swap the numbers around. It says the next minimal n digit number, and -1 if there isn't one,  how does one come to 132?

Comment: The problem says that upon recieveing an integer, let's say `154`, to find the next number with the same sum of digits. For example, the sum of `154` is `10`, so the next number with that sum will be `163` because the sum is also `10` (1 + 6 + 3)

Comment: @italy: no, but this is here a consequence of the fact that the sum should be equal. Since `124`, `125`, `126`, `127`, `128`, `129`, `130`, `131` all have different sums.

Comment: It seems to be just sum all the digit of the number (123 -> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6), then find the next number that comes after that that has the same sum of digits. 132 is the next number after 123 that has the same sum of digits (6).

Comment: The solution is quite simpel: if the value is less than `9` from the first number with `n+1` digits, then it is `n+9`. I leave the else case as an exercise, although the reasoning is similar.

Answer (score 2):

> can someone please clarify, is it just changing one digit or more than one?

Change as many digits as needed, as long as the new number is greater than the original number, and has the same number of digits as the original.

For example, if the input is 0200, then 0011 is not an acceptable solution, because 0011 is less than 0200.

1100 is also an incorrect solution, because there is a smaller number that sums to 2: 1001

Another example, when input is 9999, the solution 18999 is incorrect because it has 5 digits, and 9999 has only 4 digits.